# How to iterate through rows after group by in spark scala dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the below columns , df1

```
Following the example there:
Project_end_date               I_date     Project_start_date  id
Jan 30 2017            Jan 10 2017            Jan 1 2017      1
Jan 30 2017            Jan 15 2017            Jan 1  2017     1
Jan 30 2017            Jan 20 2017            Jan 1 2017      1
```

Here you would fist find the differences between i and start date, which would be 10, 15, and 20 days. Then you would express those as a percentage of the project's duration, so 100*10/30=33%, 100*15/30=50%, 100*20/20=67%. Then you would obtain the mean (33%), min(33%), max(67%), etc of these.

how to achieve this after doing group by on id

df.groupby("id"). ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to add the value you care about just before the `groupBy`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import spark.implicits._

df.withColumn("ival", (
    $"I_date" - $"Project_start_date") /
    ($"Project_end_date" - $"Project_start_date"))
    .groupBy('id').agg(
        F.min($"ival").as("min"),
        F.max($"ival").as("max"),
        F.avg($"ival").as("avg")
    )
```

If you want to avoid the `withColumn` you can just get the expression for `ival` inside `F.min`, `F.max` and `F.avg`, but that's more verbose.